# How to check for certain numbers in an If-else statment in C#

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to check if a value starts with three certain numbers in an if/else statement?

```
If objgoals.OurCenter.StartsWith("706") Then
    objgoals.SportsComplex = "K"            
Else
    objgoals.SportsComplex = "A"
```

Comment: If objgoals.OurCenter.StartsWith("706") Then 

objgoals.SportsComplex= "K"

        Else

objgoals.SportsComplex= "A"

Comment: What sort of *value* is `OurCenter`... is it a string or a numeric type, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

if OurCenter is a string, then your code should already be fine but if its a numerical value, you have to convert it to its string representation.

I don't have the right computer to test it but you can try something like

```
If objgoals.OurCenter.toString().StartsWith("706") .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your OurCenter member is a number, you can do it using the MOD operator. Suppose your OurCenter is a 7 digit number, this code should work:

```
if (objgoals.OurCenter % 7090000 < 10000) {
    objgoals.SportsComplex= "K";
}
```

Adjust the divider and remainder based on the number of digits in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Supossing that your variable is number, cast to string, and check if starts with the numbers that you're asking.
For example:

`if(objgoals.OurCenter.ToString().StartsWith("706")) { // Then... }`